# Find top two values from a column selected as drop down in another sheet

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have two sheets:
Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2

In sheet 2, we select the column name in sheet 1 as the dropdown menu. How can I get the top two values of the column selected?

I used the `LARGE()` function to find the top two.

[image]

Comment: Do you have Office 365, than look into TAKE() and FILTER or XLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MATCH` to get column number, `INDEX` to get values of that column, `SORT`/`TAKE` to get 2 highest values:

```
=TAKE(SORT(INDEX(A2:C6,,MATCH(F2,A1:C1,0)),1,-1),2)
```

Or `FILTER` instead of `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A2:C6,A1:C1=F2),1,-1),2)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The first formula uses kind of old-fashioned (almost obsolete) functions i.e. if you have `TAKE` and `SORT` then you have `CHOOSECOLS` and `XMATCH` and most importantly, `XLOOKUP`: `=TAKE(SORT(CHOOSECOLS(A2:C6,XMATCH(F2,A1:C1)),,-1),2)` or better `=TAKE(SORT(XLOOKUP(F2,A1:C1,A2:C6),,-1),2)`, the latter having one character more than your 2nd formula if you remove the default `1`, which makes me wonder why is one better than the other?

Comment: Just sharing another observation. If the header is not found, the `FILTER` formula will return a `#CALC!` error while the other formulas will return a `#N/A` error. The `FILTER` formula will return a `#DIV/0!` error whether any header or the matching data column contains an error. The other formulas will fail with a `#N/A` only if the matching header or matching column contains an error.

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you for your observations! While I understand the first part of mixing of "old" and "newer" functions (my bad) I don't get your remark on FILTER vs XLOOKUP. Is it a real question, rhetorical or irony?

Comment: I guess errors in data are always a subtle subject and depends on situation whether you want to have an error in "early" stage as indicator of corrupt data or later, Anyway thank you of indicating differences as I had never thought of it myself before!

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that in cell J6 is the drop down put this two formulas in L6 and L7

```
=LARGE(INDIRECT(HLOOKUP(J6,A1:C1,1,FALSE)&":"&HLOOKUP(J6,A1:C1,1,FALSE)),1)
=LARGE(INDIRECT(HLOOKUP(J6,A1:C1,1,FALSE)&":"&HLOOKUP(J6,A1:C1,1,FALSE)),2)
```

Comment: To add the sheet name to J6 replace with Sheet1!J6,  the source and result cells in this case are on sheet2.